# Vue Test Util can't find BootstrapVue html elements in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I have a project in Nuxt.js and I am trying to test it using Vue Test Util which works effectively except on files where I use BootstrapVue custom html elements.

When I run `npm test` this error displays for every BootsrapVue html element.

```
 console.error
      [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <b-container> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
      
      found in
      
      ---> <Anonymous>
             <Root>
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup `bootstrap-vue` in your Jest enviroment, using a Jest setup file.

Create the setup file:

```js
// @/jest-setup.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

Then configure [Jest's `setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) to load it:

```js
// @/jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['./jest-setup.js'],
}
```

Comment: Well since this is a Nuxt project I don't have a `main.js` file, is there a way to solve this without it?

Comment: Ok, then you'd still need to setup `bootstrap-vue` in your Jest environment, and the same steps would apply other than having to edit `main.js`.

Comment: Then I get this error:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

       5 | import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
       6 | 
    >  7 | Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
         | ^
       8 | Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
       9 | 
      10 | 

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (jest-setup.js:7:1)

Comment: That implies you don't have Babel setup properly for Jest. You could workaroudn that by replacing `import` with `require` statements (e.g., `import  Vue from 'vue'` becomes `const Vue = require('vue')`).

Comment: It works! In my case using Cypress to test components. But bootstrap components not rendering, I added this code to cypress/support which can  work, thanks a lot.